# I am very new to writing code and am struggling two link the code for a label in a GUI and the Code for an API

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have coded both the GUI and the API separately, i tried a couple different ways of linking the two. but thought just posting the bare bone structure would be easiest that way only the code to link the two would need to be discussed.
The code for the GUI is what follows

```
from tkinter import *
def weather_search():


    root = Tk()

    root.title("Weather")
    root.geometry("800x600")

    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid() #This puts the frame into the grid
    label = Label(app, text = "Weather")
    label.grid()

    location_label = Label(root,text = "Enter a Location")
    location_entry = Entry(root)

    location_label.grid(row=1, column = 1) 
    location_entry.grid(row=1, column = 2)
```

Guessing this is what i will have to link to the API. But this is also where my limited experience  is causing the problems.

```
    user_location = location_entry.get()
    print(user_location)
```

I tried using this but i am sure there is more that needs to be done.

```
    root.mainloop()

weather_search()

#the code for the API is what follows

import requests

city = input("Enter: ")

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=46346a863b94cd3b89bad166fed78b7d&units=metric'.format(city)

res = requests.get(url)
data = res.json()

print(res)
print(data)
```

I am not sure if i would need a search function for once the location is entered.

Comment: Please do not start your text with a `#` unless it is within a code block (That's what's giving all the bolding to text). I had a go at editing them out but, towards the end, I couldn't tell what was supposed to be a solid block of code, or interspersed with dialogue. You can edit your question to fix this.

Comment: Please explicit the desired output. A first guess is that you want the user to be able to enter the city location in the GUI, and then display the information. To do so, you need to create a StringVar and add it as a textvariable to your Entry.

Comment: It is rather unclear what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to get the location from the entry.

The usual way is to associate the entry with a `StringVar` which serves as a kind of link to the value in the entry.

An easy way of knowing when to read the entry is when the user hits the RETURN key, so I'll bind it to the entry. The callback function then reads the entry and sets the `city` variable.

Also I'm setting focus to entry so you won't have to click in it to enter location.

I thought the idea of putting the GUI in a function seemed a bit unusual so I rewrote it as I would have.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.geometry("800x600")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid() #This puts the frame into the grid
label = Label(app, text = "Weather")
label.grid()

def read_entry(event):  # Entry ENTER key callback function
    global city
    city = location.get()
    print(city)

location_label = Label(root,text = "Enter a Location")
location_label.grid(row=1, column = 1)

location = StringVar()  # Create a StringVar
location_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=location) # Assign textvariable
location_entry.grid(row=1, column = 2)
location_entry.bind('<Return>', read_entry) # Bind ENTER key to function
                                            # that reads entry
location_entry.focus_set()  # Sets keyboard focus to entry

root.mainloop()
```

Now the rest of your code can use the variable `city` when you exit `mainloop`. But you'll have to either exit mainloop or put the rest of your code inside the GUI code.

Comment: Thanks so much, appreciate the time you took to help!